# should I use different actions or single action?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, web

I am building a web API doing simple operations, it receives one or two params, do some calculations according to the request type, save results to the DB and returns the result. I am wondering which option is better? having different actions for each request type (domain/myapi/operation1/, domain/myapi/operation2/, ...) or just have single action and differentiate using additional parameter (Operation Type).

Comment: Single action might be better.

Comment: @JohnKennedy why?

Comment: You would have much less code.

Comment: I'd suggest to use two different action methods as both are doing different tasks. You may call different Action methods based on the Operation.

Comment: @RakeshBurbure even though, how can i benefit from that?

Comment: Separation of concerns you can say. different actions in different action methods.